# Issues with waterfall and bar plots in SHAP

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, shap

I'm trying to display waterfall plots for a binary classification problem. My code is the following:

```
mod_choice = XGBClassifier(alpha=0.5, gamma=0.5, learning_rate=0.2, max_depth=5, n_estimators=50, random_state=13, scale_pos_weight=50) # # alpha=0.5, gamma=0.5, learning_rate=0.1, max_depth=5, n_estimators=50, random_state=13, scale_pos_weight=50
```

And then:

```
mod_choice.fit(X_train, Y_train)

explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(mod_choice, X_train_ada, model_output='probability')
shap_values = explainer(X_validation)

shap.plots.waterfall(shap_values[19])
```

When I visualize the waterfall plot, I see that the base value is high (0.60) and the same of course holds in the logit scale (namely, it is higher than 1). However, when I look at my data, I see that the predicted probability for the positive class is quite low (0.11). I do not understand why then I have a base value so high - it seems, from SHAP, that the probability of the outcome equal to 1 is not aligned with the actual data distribution in the test set.

Moreover, to get rid of this problem I tried to use `shap.plots.bar(shap_values[19])`  which conveys a slightly different information but would suffice for my goals. Yet, I noticed that no feature values are shown on the y-axis, as per documentation. Instead, I only see the feature names.

How to fix the first problem (or the second)?

Comment: Hello, Maybe if we can get to see the initial shap plot you generated so we can get some clarity on the question. Also if possible, you provide the data so we can reproduce the problem, it will be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Would you mind presenting [reprex] ?

Comment: For the first question, I'm guessing it's partially due to the fact that you're using scale_pos_weight=50. Turn that back down to 1 and see what base_value you get.